# How to check if a given object is an instance of the class name given in a String?

Tags: java, instanceof

I have the following variables

```
MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
String myString = "myPackage.MyObj";
```

where `MyObj` look like this

```
package myPackage;

class MyObj {
    private String one;
    private String two;
}
```

How can I check if `myObj` is an instance of the full qualified class name as represented by the string `myString`?

Comment: Do you mean `myObj instanceof MyObj`???

Comment: We all believe the OP meant `instanceof type` where type is given as `String`. That's the version we stick to :-).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`Class#isInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) for this.

```
if (Class.forName(myString).isInstance(myObj)) {
   // myObj is an instance of the class as specified by myString.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand you correctly, but this might help you:

```
Number n = 42;      //Integer, try 42L (Long)
String type = "java.lang.Integer";
//if(n instanceof type)  //?!?
if(Class.forName(type).isAssignableFrom(n.getClass())) {
    //...
}
```